# updating failed. the response is not a valid json response. WordPress website is on maintenance mode and when I want to publish a page it shows this

Tags: json, wordpress, error-handling, custom-wordpress-pages, maintenance-mode

From Permalinks URLs are set to "Post", and Simple SSL is activated but when I want to create a new page, "Home" for example, and publish I get the "updating failed. the response is not a valid JSON response" error on WordPress.
The site is in maintenance mode.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score -1):

Change this line on apache.conf  this may fix the issue.

```
AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All
```

Refer: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/updating-failed-the-response-is-not-a-valid-json-response-32/